# What are the equations that iOS uses for velocity/acceleration when swiping?

Tags: ios, math, gesture

I'm curious as to the equations used to calculate velocity, acceleration etc. when swiping between screens on the iOS home screen and the like. 
Does anyone have any idea what they would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be in flash 5 and action script, but this is just too good not to throw out there: [easing](http://www.gizma.com/easing/).  The equations are below the ball demonstration, and though they may be in a different language, they are easily translatable as most of the actual math is plain.